# pymysql.err.InternalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x8F\\xB3\\xEF\\xB8...'

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

Всех приветствую ! Я парсю этот [новостной ресурс](https://ru.sputniknews.kz).После чего спарщенные данные(заголовок,дата,текстовой контент) заношу в БД.И вот при парсинге [этой страницы](https://ru.sputniknews.kz/world/20190904/11435177/iran-letnyaya-devochka-brak.html) .

У меня **Pymysql**(библиотека которую я использую для insert'a в БД) ругается на текстовой контент страницы. 
Судя по **traceback:**

> pymysql.err.InternalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8F\xB3\xEF\xB8...' for column 'item_text_content' at row 1")

Вот текстовой контент на которую ругается **Pymysql:**

> This a wedding party for girl who is under 13 years old. I cried when
>   I received this video from Bahmai County which is a county in
>   Kohgiluyeh and Boyer-Ahmad Province in Iran. Under Islamic laws 13
>   year old girl can marry but cannot chose her dress code.
>   pic.twitter.com/gqIQZDUcju — Masih Alinejad ️ (@AlinejadMasih)
>   September 2, 2019

Как  стало понятно **Pymysql**  ругается именно на этот `️` символ из всего текста.

> **Пробовал ставить в столбец `item_text_content` сравнение `utf8mb4_bin` не помогло**
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код подключения к БД.

> ```
> connection = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost',
>                              user = 'root',
>                              password = '',
>                              db = 'news_portal',
>                              charset = 'utf8',
>                              autocommit = True)
> cursor = connection.cursor()
> ```

**Вопрос:Как это решить ? Какое решение вы считаете лучшим в данном случае?**

**UPD:**

```
sql = "insert into items (`item_link`,`item_title`,`item_datetime`,`item_text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.execute(sql,(str(resource_link),str(item_title),str(item_datetime),str(item_text_content)))
```

Ругается на `item_text_content`

> `item_text_content = get_text_content(item_page,text_rule,text1_rule)`

Вот сама функция `get_text_content`

> ```
> def get_text_content(item_page,text_rule,text1_rule):
>     if item_page is None:
>         return
>     soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, 'lxml')
>     item_text = soup.find(text_rule[0],{text_rule[1]:text_rule[2]})
>     if item_text is not None:
>         item_text = soup.find(text_rule[0],{text_rule[1]:text_rule[2]}).text
>     else:
>         if (len(text1_rule) == 3):
>             item_text = soup.find(text1_rule[0],{text1_rule[1]:text1_rule[2]}).text
>         else:
>             item_text = ''
>     return item_text
> ```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос кусочек кода с проблемной строкой. Кст, а в `pymysql.connect(` у вас указано `charset='utf8'` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11083221/5909792)?

Comment: @gil9red,да в подключении  к БД указано.Сейчас добавлю кусок кода

Comment: А что насчет utf8mb4 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20349552/5909792)? Больше инфы: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30074553/5909792, там написано, что например если присутствуют эмодзи, то используй utf8mb4: `such as emoji, use "utf8mb4"`

Comment: @gil9red,utf8mb4 мне не помог.Я его ставил в сравнении utf8mb4.(скриншот сверху)

Comment: @gil9red,по этой ссылке(stackoverflow.com/a/30074553/5909792) я заметил такую вещь `For a supplementary character, utf8[/utf8mb3] cannot store the character at all, while utf8mb4 requires four bytes to store it.`То есть `Для дополнительного символа utf8 [/ utf8mb3] не может хранить символ вообще, в то время как utf8mb4 требуется четыре байта для его хранения.` В итоге как я понял:`utf8mb4` должен работать

Comment: @gil9red,Но `utf8mb4` почему-то не работает.Или я его как-то не правильно указал?

Comment: Вы не забыли прописать utf8mb4 прямо в нужную таблицу и нужный столбец?

Comment: Прописать ? Я просто указал в сравнение `utf8mb4` в нужную мне таблицу и в нужный мне столбец через PhpMyAdmin

Comment: Сравнение тут вообще ни при чём, вам нужно изменить кодировку хранения данных в таблице

Comment: @andreymal,сейчас попробую это сделать через PhpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взято отсюда [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc)
Мой вольный перевод схожей проблемы, правда там коннект через JDBC, но смысл тот-же.

Теория

Utf8 в MySQL's допускает только сиволы Unicode, они должны быть представлены 3 байтами в UTF-8. Здесь вы имеете символ требующий 4 байт.

Если версия вашего MySQL 5.5 или более поздняя вы можете изменить кодировку вашего поля с utf8 на utf8mb4. Эта кодировка поддерживает хранение 4 байт в UTF-8.

Вы также можете задать параметр сервера character_set_server как utf8mb4  в конфигурационном файле MySQL. Это выглядит так [connector-j-reference-charsets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html)

Два примера решения с рестартом базы и без

Решение 1.

1. Измените файл my.cnf как в примере

   [mysql]

   default-character-set=utf8mb4

   [mysqld]

   character-set-server=utf8mb4

   collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

это поможет быть уверенным, что база данных и character_set_client, character_set_connection, character_set_results используют utf8mb4 по умолчанию.

2 Перезапустите MySQL

3 Измените кодировку таблицы и столбца на utf8mb4

4 НЕ ЗАДАВАЙТЕ  кодировку в своём подключении, потому-что это переопределит character_set_client, character_set_connection, character_set_results в utf8

============================

Решение 2 (без рестарта)

1 Измените кодировку таблицы и столбца на utf8mb4

2 используйте кодировку UTF-8 в вашем подключении

3 Пишите ваши sql команды как в примере ниже
 'SET NAMES utf8mb4;INSERT INTO Mytable ...';

В этой теме есть комментарий, что второй способ сработал для insert'a. Так же там есть инструкция как верно сделать select.